# Vagrant phpmyadmin php show as plain text issue

Tags: php, centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm having some issues with phpmyadmin that i installed on a virtual machine using vagrant. I downloaded the vagrant file from puphpet it's a Centos with php, mysql, nodejs, and apache.

Default installation works fine, already edited my vhost file on my local machine to access centos /var/www folder and php it's working there, but phpmyadmin folder it's showing plain text rather than executing the php code of the index.php, the weird thing is that only phpmyadmin is not executing php code.

My local setup is Mac OS X el capitan, my vhost cents.dev point to /var/www folder.

Couldn't find any solution online.
I installed phpmyadmin using yum command, then made a link in my /var/www folder, that didn't work, the moved the phpmyadmin folder to /var/www and still doesn't work

**phpinfo is:**

```
Linux local.puphpet 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
Server API  FPM/FastCGI
PHP 5.6.15 (cli)
```

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin uses shorttags for php (`<?` instead of `<?php`).

Edit your php.ini to support that.

```
short_open_tag = On
```

And then restart your webserver

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: That didn't work, short_open_tag was set on Off, already changed, but my phpmyadmin file uses <?php